# Probability of Heads in a coin

Tags: probability

I was wondering, if you flip a fair coin $5$ times, whether you can calculate the probability of getting at least one head is calculated like this:

You can do the complement of getting at least one head which is TTTTT: $\dfrac1{2^5} =\dfrac1{32}$

Then you do $$1-\frac1{32}= \frac{31}{32}\;,$$ so that's the possibility of getting at least one head after a flip?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. This technique is often called *complementary counting*.

Comment: Very short but convincing!